# Anchor link to an answer (at top of answer)

Tags: feature-request

In most documentation these days, anchor links to specific sections are very widely used.

I want to share the 2nd answer down on this page with some folks. Naturally, I look around for a paragraph symbol or something with a hover event tied to it. Ideally, it feels like it would be to the left of the number of votes
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39825582/5739514

It's a really long answer. So I scroll all the way down, and, eventually, I find the share button. A hoverable anchor link could be a nice addition. Especially with some light orange color palettes applied to it.

Example:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror